# Go maps - pulling records based off key value. A question of search speed and behavior

Tags: arrays, sorting, go

Trying to understand how Go `maps` works, via a simple speed test.

Pulling ONLY the value of a key (via index) is really fast, I'm talking about on average around ~`50.0µs` according to my code below.

When I pull the entire record, which contains that unique key value and a handful of other keys. I'm getting speeds that fluctuate around ~`500.0µs`. I understand this is already fast and less than a millisecond. But why would pulling the entire record, if it's already indexed, take almost 10x as long?

Is it the extra key's in the record that have to be processed which requires more run time?

Am I using maps wrong in my code? Is this something to be worried about with more data over time?

I even sort my struct based off the unique key that I'm searching for.

```golang
type TravelItenariesCSV struct {
    ...
    FlightNum  int `csv:"flight_num"`
    ...

}
```

```
// Print code run time
func PrintExecutionTime(t time.Time) {
    fmt.Println("Execution time: ", time.Since(t))
}
```

```
    flightNum := vars["flight"] // Get unique int value that I need to find across all TravelItenariesCSV.FlightNum keys
    
    startTime := time.Now()
    itenariesMap := map[int]int{}

    for _, v := range s.TravelItenariesCSV { //s.TravelItenariesCSV is a slice of the struct above
        itenariesMap[v.FlightNum] = i
    }

    if v, ok := itenariesMap[i]; ok {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, utils.PrettyPrint(s.TravelItenariesCSV[v])) // this takes ~500.0µs
        //fmt.Fprintf(w, utils.PrettyPrint(v)) // this takes ~50.0µs

    }
    defer utils.PrintExecutionTime(startTime)
```

Would appreciate clarity on the subject matter.

Answer (score 2):

Your measurement of performance contains other elements:

```
if v, ok := itenariesMap[i]; ok {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, utils.PrettyPrint(s.TravelItenariesCSV[v])) // this takes ~500.0µs
        //fmt.Fprintf(w, utils.PrettyPrint(v)) // this takes ~50.0µs

    }
    defer utils.PrintExecutionTime(startTime)
```

does 2 things: fmt.Printf takes time. For 1 variable it will be x, it will scale accordingly for 10x the parameters

Second: When measuring throughput, do not use defer: Defer runs later (hence the term defer).

So to measure the map performance you could do:

```
for _, v := range s.TravelItenariesCSV { //s.TravelItenariesCSV is a slice of the struct above
        itenariesMap[v.FlightNum] = i
    }
utils.PrintExecutionTime(startTime)

rest of the code
```

That should give you a better throughput estimate